# Как восстановить текстовый документ OpenDoсument в Linux

Tags: linux

Как восстановить текстовый документ OpenDoсument в Linux

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант,использовать утилиту "foremost" :

```
sudo apt-get install foremost
```

Отзывы об этой проге отличные и добавление формата для меня показалось более простым.

Редактируем файл:

```
/etc/foremost.conf
```

копируем из него:

```
#   txt y   100000  -----BEGIN\040PGP
```

Вписываем ниже и изменяем на:

```
#   ini y   100000  -----BEGIN\040PGP
```

После чего убираем спереди #

Запускаем:

```
foremost /dev/sda2
```

Результат восстановленных файлов получите здесь:

`/home/ВАШ_ЛОГИН/output/` (директория output образуется в той директории из которой запускается программа)

Можно указывать нужные вам для поиска расширения и пути для сохранения, пример:

```
foremost -t doc -o /home/ВАШ_ЛОГИН/recovered/ /dev/sda2
```